# Bag Identification

Tags: part-identification

[image]I have a random bag #3 from an unknown set. Bag has normal 135149 number and 2011 on it. The pieces are all light gray, dark gray, black and green!?! any ideas on what set it might be?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to this site. Bag number and copyright date mean nothing (they merely identify the bag design and give a lower limit for when the set was produced (2011 in this case)). Can you post a picture of the bag and its contents?

Comment: Hopefully pics help!

Answer (score 12):

This bag is from [76003-1: Superman: Battle of Smallville](http://brickset.com/sets/76003-1/Superman-Battle-of-Smallville), based on

- [Plate 6X6](http://brickset.com/parts/4211474) in Medium Stone Grey
- [Technic Brick 1X12, Ø4,9](http://brickset.com/parts/4211860) in Medium Stone Grey
- [Roof Tile 1X3/25°](http://brickset.com/parts/4107637) in Dark Green

and Technic 3M Beam in yellow + Plate 2X3 in Brick Yellow are also in this set

Comment: Beat me by 12 seconds! Good job, I agree on 76003.

Comment: Beat me by 40 minutes, I should have kept checking back to see if someone had answered. How did you do it?